# Bypass Printdialog in IE11

Tags: printing, internet-explorer-11

I use the the below code for bypass print dialog in IE11.

```js
function PrintWindow() {

        var isIE11 = !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv[ :]*11\./);
        if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer" || isIE11== true) {

            var PrintCommand = '<OBJECT ID="PrintCommandObject" WIDTH=0 HEIGHT=0 ';
            PrintCommand += 'CLASSID="CLSID:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2"></OBJECT>';
            document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', PrintCommand);
            PrintCommandObject.ExecWB(6, 2); PrintCommandObject.outerHTML = "";
            window.close();

        }

        else {

              window.print();
        }

      }
```

it works fine when i run in localhost. but when i move the same to server
and run, it shows the below error

SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'ExecWB'

My IE version : 11.309
PHP : 5.6.30

cam someone help me to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I change the the following setting's in my browser(IE 11)

1. Internet options -> Security -> Trusted Sites - > Custom Level 'Initialise and script Activex....' - > Enable
2. Add my site to Trusted Sites.